# Grafana: ip and port of your graphite-web or graphite-api install

Tags: graphite, grafana

Trying to connect graphite with grafana. The manual [says](http://docs.grafana.org/datasources/graphite/):

> Url   The http protocol, ip and port of your graphite-web or
>   graphite-api install.

Where I can find either of them? I grep-ed /opt/graphite/, and the only 'graphite-web' related thing I found had relation to url I'm using to open basic graphite screen (the one with tree and graphite composer). I tried this url but got orange 'Unknown error' at grafana's 'Edit data source' (no errors in /var/log/grafana/* or the main log).

They both are on the same server, so I used http://127.0.0.1:81/graphite/ (curl shows `<title>Graphite Browser</title>` and frameset)

I was unable to found graphite-api at all.

grafana-4.0.1

Graphite... Well, I haven't find how to check version but it was instaslled few days ago by `pip install https://github.com/graphite-project/graphite-web/tarball/master`

Could anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed:

1. open developer tool and check console log.
2. switched 127.0.0.1 to IP I can use in my desktop browser. Have no idea why it cannot be communicated directly and have to jump back and forth across the globe
3. see XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://example.com/graphite//metrics/find/?query=*. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.com/grafena' is therefore not allowed access.
4. Add this to apache virtualhost config at the graphite side:

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"`

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET, OPTIONS, POST"`

`Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: "origin, authorization,accept, content-type"`

then `apachectl -t && apachectl graceful`

That's all.